# Distinct non-negative integers $y<9$ such that $f(y) ≡ 0 (\bmod 9)$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that if $a$ is any integer and the polynomial $f(x) = x^2 +ax+ 1$ factors (poly mod 9), then there are **THREE** distinct non-negative integers $y$ less than $9$ such that $f(y) ≡ 0 (\bmod 9)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ mod $\,9,\,$ the discriminant is a square iff it is $\equiv 0\,$ iff  $\,f(x) = (x\!-\!a)^2,\,$ and then

$$ 9\mid (x\!-\!a)^2\iff 3\mid x\!-\!a\iff x\equiv a,\,a\!+\!3,\,a\!+\!6\!\!\pmod{9}$$

Alternatively: the only factorizations mod $3$ are $\,(x\pm1)^2.\,$ Examine how those lift mod $9$.

Comment: Hey okay, I understand. But now what do I do

Comment: @Miss We're done, since the above shows there are exactly $3$ roots $\,a,\, a\!+\!3,\, a\!+\!6\pmod{9}\ \ $

Comment: Okay. So I'll be fine with just that?

Comment: What do you mean by lift mod 9